# Change appearance of standard widgets

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-widget

What is the easiest way to change the appearance of standard widgets like `Button`, `Spinners`, `ListView`, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check: [Applying Styles and Themes to the UI](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyingStyles).

Comment: Does that mean I can use different images for those components? In case I want a button background designed by me, can I use that as a theme / style?

Comment: Yes, see http://blog.androgames.net/40/custom-button-style-and-theme/ for creating a button style specifically.